# What are useful purposes for ETC's?

Tags: gold, etc

My question is related to a video where the narrator claimed that there was no case known to him where someone was able to receive his ownership of gold from an Exchange Traded Commodity (ETC) in physical form.

If that is generally true, then what is the use of ETC's? Because then they should not be necessarily useful in a crisis if one can't claim his gold.

I am thankful for any help.

Comment: What makes you think gold would be useful in a crisis?

Comment: It may be a late point in time to try to receive the gold if there already is a crisis. However, you quote *no case known to him*. What does it mean?

Comment: That nobody he knew from his friends/acquaintances was able to receive his gold from the ETC.

Comment: @JohnFx What could be the point against this?

Comment: @user99327 No specific point against it. But I'm not a believer that gold is a very good hedge against a crisis. I suppose it depends on the crisis, but I can't think of one where owning gold would put you in any better position to weather it.

Comment: Did he explain why his acquaintances were not able to receive their gold? How many people did he ask? What did the do to get the gold. What ETCs have they bought?

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Unfortunately I can not answer any this questions on a satisfying level because it was not made clear in the video. This issue wasn't of course the topic of the video, it was just some side comment. I just wanted to know if that supposed myth is true, maybe for example a personal experience of many users here contradicts that was what I actually wanted to get to know.

Comment: @JohnFx Thank you so far for your contribution. Of course gold is bought countercyclically on the market, so there is some correlation. I don't know, if you know some alternative, but the actual question is different.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange Traded Commodities (ETCs) are intended to make it easier for investors to get exposure to commodities without trading the underlying futures contracts or taking physical delivery. They can be bought and sold on stock exchanges and bid ask spreads are a lot lower than if buying and selling physical commodities. Also, there is no storage cost, as with physical commodities.

**That is the use of ETCs**: getting exposure to commodities without the hassle and expense of physical ownership, or even of trading them on a commodities exchange.

If you REALLY want to be able to take physical delivery of your ETC gold fund, you can do that in at least one circumstance.

Deutsche Börse Commodities appears to allow [physical delivery of gold ETCs](https://www.xetra-gold.com/en/gold-news/what-is-an-etc-how-investors-can-trade-commodities-on-the-exchange/):

> When choosing a provider such as Xetra-Gold, where investors have the
> right to delivery of the securitised amount of physical gold, they can
> combine the benefits of exchange trading with physical ownership of
> the commodity.

Comment: Isn't the storage cost included in the management expenses of the fund?

Comment: @Flux Not necessarily. It depends on the particular ETC's holdings. If it is in futures contracts, then no, you aren't paying for storage costs. For something like that Xetra-Gold ETC, then yes, storage costs would probably be included in the management expenses of the fund.